# how to rewrite the postgresCatalog to oracleCatalog?

Tags: oracle, flink-sql

how to rewrite the postgresCatalog to oracleCatalog?
now flinksql only surpport the postgres to store the metadata,if i want obtain the oracle metadata,how can i rewrite the postgresCatalog?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There is an open ticket for adding an OracleCatalog to Flink, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17508

If you want to implement this yourself, I would recommend to have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16471 and https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/11336 which are the original ticket and the pull request that introduced the PostgresCatalog to Flink. You could use those to determine how the implementation of an OracleCatalog would look like.

Comment: thank you for your anwser,which is very helpful.